# android menu icon size

Tags: android, menu, icons, menuitem

I need to set the menu icon programmatically (Not through a layout file), and also I need to load the icon file from file:///android_asset/ (Not load as a compiled Drawable). I found the size of the displayed icon is relatively smaller. It looks like android resize it or something, and I do not want to achieve the same effect with out code.

As you can see in the in the attached screen shot, the menu "globe-36", "globe-48" and "globe-72" is populated using code like, and their image are 36x36, 48x48 and 72x72 : (This is the way I load my icon in my app, I have to)

```
            MenuItem mi = menu.add(Menu.NONE, i++, i++, icon);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open(icon + ".png"), icon);
            mi.setIcon(d);
```

And, the menu "globe-aset" and "barcode-asset" are populated like:

```
    MenuItem mi = menu.add(Menu.NONE, i++, i++, "globe-asset");
    mi.setIcon(R.drawable.globe);
```

[image]

Comment: Does that depend on the screen resolution?

Comment: What is the resolution of R.drawable.globe? Is your screen xhdpi?

Comment: TO set the Icon Pramaticallly

[Load-activity-and-or-application-logo-programmatically-from-manifest][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105504/load-activity-and-or-application-logo-programmatically-from-manifest

Answer (score 12):

The sizes of menu icons are:

- ldpi: 36x36
- mdpi: 48x48
- hdpi: 72x72
- xhdpi: 96x96
- xxhdpi: 144x144

as your **globe-asset** is about twice as large as the **globe-48** I assume that your screenshot is from an xhdpi device which expects the menu icons as 96x96.

Comment: For newer info, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639263/whats-the-correct-size-icon-for-drawable-xxhdpi