# Load Activity and/or Application Logo Programmatically from Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to load the logo associated with the current activity and/or its parent application from the definition in the manifest. This technique has already worked successfully on loading the title and icon associated with both, but the logo is always returning `null` or 0.

Here is the relevant info from the manifest I am working with:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/ad_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ad_logo">
```

With `activity` being an instance of the above defined activity, I have tried the following (results annotated inline):

```
PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
ComponentName cn = activity.getComponentName();
ApplicationInfo ai = activity.getApplicationInfo();

//ACTIVITY LABEL: Works
pm.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).loadLabel(pm);

//APPLICATION LABEL: Works
ai.loadLabel(pm);
//APPLICATION LABEL: Works
pm.getApplicationLabel(ai);

//ACTIVITY ICON: Works
pm.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).loadIcon(pm);
//ACTIVITTY ICON: Works
pm.getActivityIcon(cn);

//APPLICATION ICON: Works
pm.getApplicationIcon(ai);
//APPLICATION ICON: Works
ai.loadIcon(pm);

//ACTIVITY LOGO: Does not work
pm.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).loadLogo(pm);
//ACTIVITY LOGO: Does not work
pm.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).logo
//ACTIVITY LOGO: Does not work
pm.getActivityLogo(cn);

//APPLICATION LOGO: Does not work
pm.getApplicationLogo(ai);
//APPLICATION LOGO: Does not work
pm.getApplicationLogo(activity.getApplication().getPackageName());
//APPLICATION LOGO: Does not work
ai.loadLogo(pm);

//APPLICATION LOGO: Does not work
pm.getApplicationInfo(ai.packageName, 0).loadLogo(pm);
//APPLICATION LOGO: Does not work
ai.logo;
```

Does anyone know how to properly load the logo for either or both of these targets?

*edit*:
Logo support requires API level 9. The devices I am testing on are emulators and physical devices all runing API level 10. This code will never be executed on 3.0+.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but perhaps having an `android:logo` in the activity also is a problem? It is an application attribute, not an activity one. Try removing the second one.

Comment: @Aleadam I noticed that it wasn't defined in [the specification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) but the method exists for loading the logo and it has been used in [Google's own examples](http://code.google.com/p/styled-action-bar/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml). I'll test.

Comment: the method is fin, I'm talking about the manifest. I'll post some more below (bue to the comment limitations)

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure you mean "This code will **always** be executed on 3.0+."

Comment: The native action bar on Android 3.0+ will automatically handle loading and displaying the logo itself. This code is only for API levels 9 and 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my tests, your code works properly running on a Honeycomb device, but not on a Gingerbread or below device.  That seems to imply that the `android:logo` functionality, although present in API Level 8, is not implemented correctly in the underlying platform.  That is, the same application apk on a Level 8-10 device is not retaining the logo attribute, but a Level 11 device does.  That means the problem is not with the code or the AndroidManifest.xml, but with the platform.

Comment: I was worried that this would be the cause. After further poking around last night I now agree that it is most certainly an issue with the OS. Quite a shame as it would have enabled a great feature in my library.

Comment: FYI this *can* be done if you use a pull-parser to go after the manifest directly. https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/c1c187739a1b69340c325577f2f02c8a60dcd717/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L267-348

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the code in `android.app.ContextImpl.ApplicationPackageManager` ([here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable%28java.lang.String%2Cint%2Candroid.content.pm.ApplicationInfo%29)), you will find that eventually it uses the method

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String packageName,int resid,ApplicationInfo appInfo)
```

(lines 2131 to 2173 in 2.3).

There are several `Log.w` calls there that you can use to follow what is going on through adb (i.e., `Failure retrieving resources for`...)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find all the applications that are installed. For this purpose us the following methods from package manager,

```
public abstract List<PackageInfo> getInstalledPackages (int flags)
```

[more info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29)

You can also use the following method for getting info on installed packages.

```
public abstract List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplications (int flags)
```

[more info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29)

Now after getting the list, iterate it using the following method.

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String packageName,int resid,ApplicationInfo appInfo)
```

[more info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getDrawable%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo%29)

Each iteration will give you the respective drawable of the package queried. here res id is the id of the icon..

```
R.drawable.icon
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jake Wharton, you are trying to retrieve something that doesn't exist. Unlike [applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html), [activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) do not have a separate logo attribute (the logo defined in the application becomes the default attribute for all activities). This is why you are unable to retrieve one from an activity.

Comment: I would settle for the application logo except I am unable to get its resource ID or drawable either. As I mention in a comment on the question, I know the manifest schema does not list a `logo` attribute, but [Google's own examples](http://code.google.com/p/styled-action-bar/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml#29) use it and it works perfectly fine on Android 3.0+.