# Programatically setting size of icon (@+android:id/icon) from Android Preference

Tags: android

I subclassed an Android Preference to load my own layout (very slightly modified), but my layout still has the built-in icon provided by the Preference class:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp/>
```

I can't retrieve a reference to the ImageView programatically like the Android Preference class does because com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.icon);
```

Is it possible to programmatically change the size. Ideally, I wouldn't create various layouts for each size I want. I think the solution here is to pass in an AttributeSet to my constructor and have it set the size of the icon, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: You are importing wrong `R` file. Import `R` with your package name.

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105504/load-activity-and-or-application-logo-programmatically-from-manifest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ImageView id declaration is wrong in xml correct it :

```
android:id="@android:id/icon"
```

Initialize ImageView this way in activity :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to `@android:id/icon` and import `android.R.id.icon`

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution:

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
imageView.setHeight(VALUE)
imageView.setWidth(VALUE)
}
})
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how I get a reference to imageView. Also, I don't think there are methods called setHeight or setWidth for image views.