# What's the correct size icon for drawable-xxhdpi?

Tags: android, drawable, dpi, android-icons

As we know, the correct sized icon:

```
* drawable-ldpi (120 dpi, Low density screen) - 36px x 36px
* drawable-mdpi (160 dpi, Medium density screen) - 48px x 48px
* drawable-hdpi (240 dpi, High density screen) - 72px x 72px
* drawable-xhdpi (320 dpi, Extra-high density screen) - 96px x 96px
```

On Jelly Bean, `drawable-xxhdpi` can be supported. So what's the correct size icon?

Comment: Today I simply copied over the higher res icons from my iOS 7 app and used them for my android app. Instead of 36px I used a 40px icon, for 48px I used 58px, for 72px I used 76px and for 96px I used 120px icon. There was a definite increase in the sharpness for the icon. I guess it is better to use higher res icons than Google recommends.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

[image: Android Icon Display Densities]

- MDPI: **48x48**
- HDPI: **72x72**
- XHDPI: **96x96**
- *XXHDPI: **144x144***
- XXXHDPI: **192x192**

> to create an icon for different densities, you should follow the 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium, high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively)

- [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Comment: can you tell me as per the android guidelines why they mentioned 180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density. Please clear this doubt. Thanks alot

Answer (score 43):

This is a quote from a post on Google Plus https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/ePQya3KsTjW by *Nick Butcher*

> The gorgeous screen on the Nexus 10 falls into the XHDPI density
>   bucket.  On tablets, Launcher uses icons from one density bucket up
>   [0] to render them slightly larger.  To ensure that your launcher icon
>   (arguably your apps most important asset) is crisp you need to add a
>   144*144px icon in the drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-480dpi folder.

So, for the xxhdpi qualifier, you will need to create an icon of the size **144*144px** for your launcher icon. You can either place it in the **drawable-xxhdpi** or the **drawable-480dpi**

EDIT: To add to the original answer to address cone of the comments by the OP.

As per this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources, alternative resources should be created using this ratio: **3:4:6:8 scaling ratio**. However, if you are concerned about loosing quality with regards to your in-app drawable resource, consider using 9-patch images wherever possible. That will reduce or eliminate any loss of quality. The Android OS all by itself, does a remarkable job handling various screen sizes most of the time anyway.

As for the icon size 144*144px, create either of these two folder **drawable-xxhdpi** or the **drawable-480dpi** and place just your launcher icon of the said size in it. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, can I copy my old icons from the xhdpi to the xxhdpi and ensure that there isn't any lost. Because I read the document from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH,there is the explain "Applications should not generally worry about this density; relying on XHIGH graphics being scaled up to it should be sufficient for almost all cases. " I am confused about it, thanks.

Comment: @JerikcXIONG: I think they are talking about graphics in general in that line. That being said, I think it would be prudent to create just the launcher icon for `xxhdpi` and let the OS handle the in-app graphics.

Comment: That's say, if I do it, it maybe bring the quality issue. Right ? And do you know how to get the 144*144 ? Is there any formula about how to get the icon's size in different situations ?

Comment: Why is 480 associated with xxhdpi?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Not sure about the **why** part. But a tooltip, on move hover, on the word `XXHDPI` shows _Extra-extra!-high density(480 dpi)_  in the [Metrics and Grids](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **add a 144*144px icon in the drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-480dpi folder.**

For more information:- 
Official G+ shows that xxhdpi is 480dpi:

https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/ePQya3KsTjW

Answer (score 1):

Standart icon size in dip is **48 dip**.

You might use this [service](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example) for creation all size icons. (Set size - 48 dip, and other settings)