# How to add images to corresponding folders in res/drawable/

Tags: android

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

The icon attribute requires a resource ID for an image. The name that follows @drawable/ must be the name of a bitmap image you've saved in your project's res/drawable/ directory. For example, "@drawable/ic_action_search" refers to ic_action_search.png.

how to add image to res/drawable/  ?? What size image needed for each type, like xxxdpi,xxdpi

Comment: Just take a look at this link, upload the image and download the res folder completely
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your First Answer Please Visit [Android ImageView example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/).Copy the image and paste into **`Eclipse/Android-Studio in the res/drawable directory`**.

> The image name should be in lowercase, otherwise it will end up with
>   an error.

You should always provide bitmap resources that are properly scaled to each of the generalized density buckets: low, medium, high and extra-high density. This helps you achieve good graphical quality and performance on all screen densities.

To generate these images, you should start with your raw resource in vector format and generate the images for each density using the following size scale:

1. xhdpi: 2.0
2. hdpi: 1.5
3. mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
4. ldpi: 0.75

This means that if you generate a 200x200 image for xhdpi devices, you should generate the same resource in 150x150 for hdpi, 100x100 for mdpi, and 75x75 for ldpi devices.

Then, place the files in the appropriate drawable resource directory:

```
Project/
    res/
        drawable-xhdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-hdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-mdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-ldpi/
            awesomeimage.png
```

Any time you reference `@drawable/awesomeimage`, the system selects the appropriate bitmap based on the screen's density.

For more details

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

[image]
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639263/whats-the-correct-size-icon-for-drawable-xxhdpi)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider mdpi as you base and using that you can create for hdpi, xhdpi and so on
eg. if you mdpi size is 12px X 12px then for hdpi it should be 18px X 18px as hdpi is 1.5 times mdpi

use this link 
[About Android image and asset sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581649/about-android-image-and-asset-sizes)

Answer (score 1):

Drag drop image using finder/explorer 
Use android design guidlines for icon size ratios

Comment: Just to add to this, android studio will not allow you to make use of a resource that has upper case letters in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your images from your syaytem to drawable directory of your project

And for icon sizes you can refer to this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12768159/4211264

Answer (score 0):

**What size image needed for each type, like xxxdpi,xxdpi**

for icon size.. please refer this site

http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/

Answer (score 0):

Go to YourProjectName/res/drawable and save your image in this folder.
If u have different sizes you can also use the different drawable folders.

If it is one image for every size just create the new folder "drawable" and save your image there.