# Drawable resources app launcher icon size

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I have some confusion regarding drawable resource icon size. As per the Android developer support guidelines [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources). I found below information

```
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon only; see note above)
```

As per the my understanding 180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density should be 144x144 (3.0x) because, if extra-high-density (96x96) is (2.0x) and extra-extra-high-density is (3.0x) So that extra-extra-high-density resolution  should be 144x144.

One more solution found here for xxhdpi app launcher icon size should be (144X144)
[Different resolution support android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/drawable-folder-for-different-resolution-and-application-icon-size)  is

```
mipmap-mdpi (48X48)
mipmap-hdpi (72X72)
mipmap-xhdpi (96X96)
mipmap-xxhdpi (144X144)
mipmap-xxxhdpi (192X192)
```

I have doubt why they mentioned  180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density. Kindly Suggest me.

Thanks for help

Comment: Use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639263/whats-the-correct-size-icon-for-drawable-xxhdpi) In this the Answer are you got. Please visit this link.                                                                                                                                   Hope u like it.

Comment: @Harshad I got most of link, that's why I am confused regarding Android developer guidelines.

Comment: see my answer link. All confusion have solve.

Comment: Thanks for effort, I saw your link then what I consider about android developer guidlines

Comment: Here is simply Calculation ;                                                                                                                     48px = 1.0x  , 96px = 2.0x , So that  48px * 3 = 144px . So the Guideline is wrong .

Comment: LDPI should be 36 x 36.

MDPI should be 48 x 48.

HDPI should be 72 x 72.

XHDPI should be 96 x 96.

XXHDPI should be 144 x 144.

XXXHDPI should be 192 x 192.

Answer (score 2):

To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the **3:4:6:8:12:16** scaling ratiobetween the six generalized densities.

For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different sizes should be:

•   36x36 (0.75x) for low-density

•   48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density

•   72x72 (1.5x) for high-density

•   96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density

•   180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density

•   192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density

Comment: Thanks for your effort but already I have mentioned stuck points.

Comment: 180* 180 is wrong XXHDPI should be 144 x 144. 192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density is wrong answer XXXHDPI should be 192 x 192.

Comment: @pankajsharma Already I found 144x144 is correct but my question is as per the android developer guidelines they have given 180x180 why?

Comment: @pankajsharma what is difference between XXXHDPI and extra-extra-extra-high-density?

Comment: then why did you give comment 192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density is wrong answer

Comment: This is the best answer with proper Explanation and values.

Answer (score 2):

```
  LDPI should be 36 x 36.

MDPI should be 48 x 48.

HDPI should be 72 x 72.

XHDPI should be 96 x 96.

XXHDPI should be 144 x 144.

XXXHDPI should be 192 x 192.
```

Comment: Already i have mentioned measure points. What I consider 180x180 is correct for xxhdpi