# Android mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi in pixels for 379x379px image?

Tags: android

I have an image (379x379px) that needs to be sent to a client in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi. I have done searching on this site as well as on Google but couldn't find a straight answer.

What dimensions does this image have to be in pixels for each (mdpi, hdpi, etc.)? The image is a vector illustration so it can be enlarged to any size.

Comment: You can convert the values from many online dpi calculators (like [this](http://jennift.com/dpical.html)). But it would really help you if you read carefully the official [android developers' site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 4):

I am using this site https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/ for converting px to dp.

For your image

```
mdpi     379.00 x 379.00 px

tvdpi    504.54 x 504.54 px     
hdpi     568.50 x 568.50 px 
xhdpi    758.00 x 758.00 px     
xxhdpi   1137.00 x 1137.00 px   
xxxhdpi  1516.00 x 1516.00 px
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer:

[What's the correct size icon for drawable-xxhdpi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639263/whats-the-correct-size-icon-for-drawable-xxhdpi)

It has the correct DPI and pixels for each size. You could scale them to those sizes and send them to the client.