# What is the solution for following lint issue - The icon has identical contents in the following configuration folders

Tags: android

I added my `Drawables` .png icons in different density folder but it is showing me lint above lint error -
The icon has identical contents in the following configuration folders: `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`.
- suggest me solution

Comment: I think you have put same icon in different folder.

Comment: what does the logcat show ?

Comment: some image files are equal in listed directories. You didn't scale them

Comment: is there any way to edit resolution of this images??

Answer (score 0):

Your images should follow the Android design guidelines. Check the image sizes in different folders. 
You should follow the 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium, high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively).

> MDPI: 48x48
>   HDPI: 72x72
>   XHDPI: 96x96
>   XXHDPI: 144x144
>   XXXHDPI: 192x192

Check this answer for a detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311302/2610010

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your icon drawable into `drawable-nodpi` (and remove all copies from other `drawable-[density]` directories)