# what resolution for creating android UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I read about dp and pixel and calculate dpi and pixel . but i am confused. I want to know if I want to create UI for my app, is better what resolution I select for beginning? I want to use of *Photoshop*. on design section in Android studio, there are e few devices with their resolutions,for example (**480 * 800 hdpi(nexus one)**) and so on . but which one is better for first create on photoshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using px for design

- Mobile: 360 x 640
- Tablet 7inch: 600 x 960
- Tablet 9inch: 1024 x 768

References

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrNoM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueFa0.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAt1u.png

Comment: Yes. This is the default template of sketch material design.

Comment: If this is fit for you, please accept it @sayreskabir

Comment: .ok but in this info Mobile: 360 x 640:  **360 x 640 is inch** ?right?

Comment: 360px x 640px sir

Answer (score 0):

Use Density-independent pixel (dp) units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.
The android documentation says  :

> A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to
>   express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
>   The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a
>   160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system
>   for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently
>   handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual
>   density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen
>   pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi
>   screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp
>   units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of
>   your UI on screens with different densities.

You can read it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

For correct icon size you should read answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639263/whats-the-correct-size-icon-for-drawable-xxhdpi)